# Bring backstack entry to the front

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I have an application with a BottomNavBar, with 3 destinations: A, B, C

The user navigates through A -> C -> B. So the backstack will be A, C, B.

Now the user clicks on A again. How can I bring the A entry to the front, so my stack will end up being C -> B -> A?
I do not want to pop all the way back to A, since I want to retain my states for all 3 destinations

Comment: You don't have to do anything just navigate and the backstack will become A,B,C,A

Comment: That's not my intended purpose. I want to bring the A destination to the front.
Having A,B,C,A is not my desire.

Comment: did you mean like youtube app? have you found the solution so far?

Comment: Not really.
What I ended up doing is checking for A and clearing the stack all the way back to A